# SQL Unpivot Text Contents

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have seen a number of examples covering pivoting a table, but none which cover text that has no standard format.

For example sake, my table would appear like the following (we have several "note" columns)

```
PK_ID  JOB_ID  NOTE1           NOTE2
-----  ------  --------------  -----------------
1      53      Some note here  Another note here
2      105     Noted text      [NULL]
3      105     [NULL]          Final Note
```

What I am after from this, would be something like the following

```
JOB_ID  PK_ID  NOTE
------  -----  --------------
53      1      Some note here
53      1      Another note here
105     2      Noted text
105     3      Final Note
```

Can anyone advise on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this works in SQL SERVER

```
SELECT 
    [PK_ID]
    ,[JOB_ID]
    ,[NOTE] 
FROM 
    Table1 
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT [NOTE1] AS [NOTE]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [NOTE2] AS [NOTE]
) T
WHERE T.NOTE IS NOT NULL
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d318/1)

Comment: Not quite sure why I didn't know that, but thank you VERY much. Works a treat.